# Find the sum of nodes in a binary search tree whose value lie in a certain range by augmenting the BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I want to augment a binary search tree such that search, insertion and delete be still supported in O(h) time and then I want to implement an algorithm to find the sum of all node values in a given range.

Comment: Sounds like a great goal.  What have you tried?  Which part are you having a problem with.  There is already lots of documentation about binary trees which you can refer to.

Comment: Well I looked around and the only thing close to this problem I found was using the segment tree which is not an augmentation. I also found a solution which basically used an AVL tree. But I want to augment the BST and then find the sum of nodes in a prticular range. I have tried adding the cumulative sum to each node from bottom to top but I stuck after that. I really have no idea for this yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you add an additional data structure to your BST class, specifically a `Hashmap` or `Hashtable`. Your `keys` will be the different numbers your BST contains and your `values` the number of occurrences for each.  BST `search(...)` will not be impacted however `insert(...)` and `delete(...)` will need slight code changes.

> Insert

When adding nodes to the BST check to see if that value exist in the Hashmap as a key.  If it does exist increment occurrence count by 1. If it doesn't exist add it to the Hashmap with an initial value of 1.

> Delete

When deleting decrement the occurrence count in the Hashmap (assuming your aren't being told to delete a node that doesn't exist)

> Sum

Now for the sum function

```
sum(int start, int end)
```

You can iteratively check your Hashmap to see which numbers from the range exist in your map and their number of occurrences. Using this you can build out your sum by adding up all of the values in the Map that are in the range multiplied by their number of occurrences.

> Complexities

Space: O(n) 
Time of sum method: O(range size).
All other method time complexity isn't impacted.

You didn't mention a space restraint so hopefully this is OK.  I am very interested to see if you can some how use the properties of a BST to solve this more efficiently nothing comes to mind for me.